# ASP.NET - pass values from one webportal to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I need some ideas on the issue that I'm facing.

I have a web-portal which has a navigation panel. When I click on a one of the navigation items which is coded like this

```
<li><a href="/Site/Controller/Action/@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SearchID)">View</a></li>
```

I am routed to another web-portal, which is independent of the first.

Now, my requirement is that I have to place a back button on the second page to get me back to the first page. I could be anywhere in the first web-portal, and when I click on the link as given above, I must be taken to the second web-portal (which works fine). But how do I get back from second page to the first (to the place where I left). I need to pass the metadata - (controller/ Action/ ID), but how do I do it using the html.Raw method?

Comment: <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you can create a partial view like _Back.cshtml with follow defintion:


@{
    string Url = ViewData["Url"] != null ? ViewData["Url"].ToString() : null;
}

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Url))
{
    <div >
        <a href=@Url> Back </a>
    </div>
}

and call where you need, eg: 
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/PartialCommon/_Back.cshtml", new ViewDataDictionary { { "Url", "desired URL" } })
```